# Shallow copy Integer in Java

Tags: java, variables

Other answers don't work for me. My question is about Integer.

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(11);
Integer i2 ;
i2 = i1;
System.out.println(i1+"   "+i2);
i1 = 233;
System.out.println(i1+"   "+i2);
//~ 11    11
//~ 233    11
```

I want to let i1 and i2 related.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. The line `i1 = 233;` changes the value of `i1` to refer to a different `Integer` object. `Integer` itself is immutable. Perhaps you want `AtomicInteger` instead, where you can modify the value within the object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In java `java.lang.Integer` is immutable. It means that you can't change the value of Integer object (in usual way). You can create new `Integer` instance with new value.

`i1` and `i2` contains a reference to the same `Integer` instance. When you made

```
i1 = 233;
```

it means that `i1` refers to another instance of `Integer` class

If you want that `i1` and `i2` refers to the same instance you can use `AtomicInteger`, but `AtomicInteger` was made for different purpose.

```
AtomicInteger i1 = new AtomicInteger(11);
AtomicInteger i2 ;
i2 = i1;
System.out.println(i1+"   "+i2);
i1.set(233);
System.out.println(i1+"   "+i2);
```

Or you can make a wrapper

```
public static class IntegerWrapper {

    private int value;

    public IntegerWrapper(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public IntegerWrapper setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and code

```
IntegerWrapper i1 = new IntegerWrapper(11);
IntegerWrapper i2 ;
i2 = i1;
System.out.println(i1.getValue()+"   "+i2.getValue());
i1.setValue(233);
System.out.println(i1.getValue()+"   "+i2.getValue());
```

Answer (score 4):

When you do this : `i2 = x;` java automatically does this `i2 = new Integer(x);`  for you because `Integer` is immutable. where x = (any integer literal)

Comment: I hope you meant `i2 = (any integer literal);`, otherwise this would be wrong.

Comment: i think its obvious. I just want to point out that a new Object is created.

Comment: Thats not at all obvious. In OP's code, `i1` and `i2` are both `Integer`s and `i2 = i1;` wouldn't create a new instance of `Integer`.

Comment: Ok strictly speaking, it does not need to  be a new object. You are right.

Comment: It would me more like `Integer.valueOf(i1)` rather than `new Integer(i1);`

Answer (score 1):

Java always creates new object on assigning new integer literal because Integer is immutable.

For ex:

```
i1=233; // it represent as i1= new Integer(233);
```

Now `i1` and `i2` as two different physical addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that `i1 = 233` changes the memory address that `i1` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing is at play here. When you assigned

```
i1=233;
```

It actually read it as

```
i1= new Integer(233);
```

Now read the code again. Your i2 integer is still pointing to the object containing 11, where as i1 is pointing to the new object containing 233.